# Fetch a list of all scheduled activities in AWS EC2 / RDS using Bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks, rds

Is there any script which fetches a list of all the scheduled activities that AWS has planned on EC2/RDS/Elasticache

AWS suggested me to use Lambda's Scheduled events, but Scheduled events just schedules something, and not fetch the list of scheduled activities. Again, it cannot access resources in a VPC.

Writing a bash script is favourable to us.

Comment: What do you mean by scheduled activities? Can you give us some examples?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Scheduled Activities according to AWS just means that you can schedule the Lambda function to execute at a fixed schedule. ie., every 1 hour, 1 day. the lowest being 5 min.

It does not give you a way to execute the function when Amazon schedules and EC2 maintenance activity

Answer (score 0):

AWS provide an SNS topic which ables you to subscribe to RDS: [AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html)

You also have something similar with ElastiCache: [AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/ECEvents.html)

For EC2, you can monitor the ASG for example: [AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASGettingNotifications.html)